# Verificar itens de uma lista em outra lista

Tags: c#, algoritmo

Estou tendo dificuldade em fazer um método para verificar 2 listas. Este método vai receber uma lista que é a lista que foi adicionada ao pedido e o Id da requisição de compra ao qual esse pedido foi associado. O método chama outro método que retorna do banco a lista de itens na requisição de compra. Assim, nesse ponto tenho 2 listas: uma recebida como parâmetro com os itens que estão sendo adicionados ao pedido, e outra que busquei no banco com os itens da requisição.

Preciso verificar se os itens que estão no pedido estão na requisição, ou seja, verificar se os itens da lista que recebi como parâmetro estão nos itens da lista que veio do banco. Caso positivo, preciso verificar se este item já foi comprado (tenho uma propriedade booleana para isso), e se não foi comprado preciso marcar essa propriedade como `true` e deixar esse item passar para ser cadastrado.

Preciso verificar também se nessas listas não tem nenhum item que não foi solicitado na requisição de compra, ou seja, o comprador não consegue comprar sem um requisição desse item.

Todos os itens que não deviam estar no pedido, seja porque já foi comprado ou porque não foi pedido, devem ser retirados pelo sistema. Após cadastrado o pedido, que tenho que exibir a lista de itens que foram retirados pelo sistema.

Sei que ficou bem grande por que é um processo complexo mas se alguém puder me ajudar com isso, eu tentei hoje o dia todo, mas sempre fica uma brecha para erros.

Codigo do Metodo

```
public ControlePedidoRCM ControlePedidoRCM(int IdRCM, List<MaterialPedido> IdMaterial)
        {
            RCMDal rd = new RCMDal();
            ControlePedidoRCM Controle = new ViewModel.ControlePedidoRCM();
            List<int> Comprados = new List<int>();
            List<int> Fora = new List<int>();

            List<MaterialRCM> itens = rd.ListarItens(IdRCM).ToList();

            foreach(var item in itens)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < IdMaterial.Count; i++)
                {
                    //se o material estiver na lista de RCM
                    if(item.MaterialID == IdMaterial[i].MaterialID)
                    {
                        if(item.Comprado == true)
                        {
                            //ja foi comprado
                            Comprados.Add(item.MaterialID);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //não está na RCM
                        Fora.Add(item.MaterialID);
                    }
                }
            }
            Controle.Comprado = Comprados;
            Controle.Fora = Fora;
            return Controle;
        }
```

Comment: Uma dica: sua pergunta está muito difícil de entender, então imagino que você está tendo problemas porque você não consegue dividir a tarefa em partes. Largue a IDE por alguns minutos e tente escrever - e em português, não em código - o que o programa deve fazer. Escreva uma sequência de passos. Depois destaque os passos que você consegue executar e os que não consegue. Isso faz com que você consiga isolar o erro mais fácil e nos ajuda a lhe ajudar.

Comment: Outra coisa que pode ajudar: já notou que vários programadores, mesmo os mais velhos, costumam ter bonequinhos em suas mesas? Arrume um bonequinho e tente explicar o seu problema para ele. [**Eu estou falando sério.**](http://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/) Pode até ser que com isso você não resolva o seu problema, mas ao menos você terá uma ideia mais clara das causas do seu problema.

Comment: @Renan Eu uso um pato de borracha.

Comment: @AlanAlmeida Você pode colocar exemplos do seu código na pergunta?

Comment: Pessoal obrigado pelas dicas, vou ver se arrumo algum bonequinho colocar na minha mesa rsrs.. quanto ao codigo ja mexi tanto nele que agora acho que ja tem longe de atingir o objetivo, vou dar uma arrumada nele pra deixar ele do jeito que ficou quando cheguei mais perto de fazer o que preciso, ai atualizo a pergunta.

Comment: Renan e Cigano, coloquei o código.

Comment: Melhorou bastante e ficou entendível agora. Só mais duas coisas: primeiro, não conhecemos toda a regra de negócio do seu cliente, por isso só podemos analisar a parte lógica de como o código funciona. Segundo, você conseguiu montar duas listas - uma de produtos "dentro" e outra de produtos "fora" da compra. O que, em não mais que cinco palavras, está faltando?

Comment: Olha, difícil em menos de cinco palavras, essa é a primeira versão desse método, o problema é, suponha que eu receba como parâmetro uma lista com 3 materiais, Ids 1, 2, 3 e na lista que veio do banco a mesma coisa, o que acontece que no Id um passa normal, mas os outros dois ele coloca na lista de itens que estão fora da requisição, ou seja, os outros dois caem no else e são colocados na lista como se estivessem fora da requisição de compra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alan,

É mais fácil para outros desenvolvedores entenderem seu código quando você segue as convenções, parâmetro em .NET começa com letra minuscula, e apesar dos nomes estranhos, espero conseguir responder sua pergunta. (ah, e antes que eu me esqueça, não há necessidade de comparar "== true", o compilador é mais esperto do que parece)

Antes de eu ir para a resposta em si, um outro detalhe, os nomes dificultam o sentido do seu código, então pode ser que eu sugira nomes que não batam com a realidade ou apenas vou inverter o sentido, pois não sei ao certo qual é seu objetivo. Mas vou tomar essa liberdade mesmo assim, pois acho que você poderia limpar bastante o código, deixando ele bem menos "complexo", o que quero dizer é que a complexidade do código não vem do requisito e sim de você mesmo.

Existe alguma restrição quanto ao uso de Linq no seu ambiente? uma das formas de verificar se elementos fazem parte de uma lista seria o seguinte:

```
var idDosMateraisNoCatalogo = rd.ListarItens(IdRCM).ToList().Select(m => m.MaterialID);

var materiaisNaListaDeRCM = materiaisRequisicao.Where(m => idDosMateraisNoCatalogo.Contains(m.MaterialID));

var materiaisForaDaListaDeRCM = materiaisRequisicao.Where(m => !idDosMateraisNoCatalogo.Contains(m.MaterialID));
```

No caso, eu troquei IdMaterial por materiaisRequisicao.

Não querendo fazer "propaganda" mas acredito ser pertinente, se quiser algumas dicas de como melhorar o design do seu código, dá uma olhada no [www.chegadegambiarra.com](http://chegadegambiarra.com)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Breno, as vezes acaba faltando um pouco de qualidade no código por que aqui na empresa infelizmente temos uma equipe muito reduzida, apenas 2 e os gerentes e donos da empresa querem tudo pra ontem.

Comment: @AlanAlmeida Você é bem-vindo! lendo novamente minha resposta, talvez eu tenha pegado um pouco pesado com você. Peço desculpas por isso. Espero que você tenha entendido a resposta e que consiga fazer uso dela para melhorar parte desse algoritmo.

Comment: Fica tranquilo, eu intendi que você só estava querendo ajudar e agradeço as dicas.